# When trying to install Wine on 12.10, 'Sudo' command will not let me type in a password

Tags: updates, wine, password, sudo

As the title explains, I have been attempting to install Wine on my laptop which is running 12.10. When I access the command terminal and entered

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
```

I was of course met by a password block, when I attempted to enter my password, it flat out wouldn't let me type anything, the only key that got a response from the terminal was "**enter**" which was met by "**incorrect password**". To bypass this issue I backed out and used the `gksudo` command, this new dialogue box seemed to give me access to sudo commands.

I then entered `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install wine1.5`.

Up until the installation everything went fine, but after entering the final command (still using `gksudo`) The terminal read "the following packages have unmet dependencies" and proceeded to list a bunch of "recommends"

So my guess is that Wine hasn't been updated to run on 12.10... Is this true, and is there any other way to open .exe's?
Also what was with that funky password mishap?
I'm totally new to Ubuntu so I've just been using support pages and tutorials, sorry if I'm a bit naive in these matters...

Comment: Regarding the "funky password misshap" - in Unix passwords are not echoed to terminal, not even as "****". This is completely normal. Just type your password and press [Enter].

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question you asked in the title of your topic:

When you type a password in a Linux shell, it doesn't show anything, on purpose.  Just go ahead and type your password and press Enter.

Take a look at the following screenshot from my computer.  I typed my password successfully at the su prompt (su is similar to sudo) but saw nothing.  My password was still entered correctly and I obtained root.

[image]

Comment: Ahh, I see, wow..And as far as my problem with Wine, I think i just needed to restart my computer to let the updates install. This is all starting to make sense to my windows conditioned mind...

Comment: @Nocturnus Also, I think the issue with Wine is on Ubuntu's end... others seem to be having similar issues.  Wait a few days, and try again.  Quantal only recently went final; there is a good chance they're still sorting things out.  By the way, I recommend installing the wine package instead of wine1.5.  That way, you will always have the latest version of Wine installed.

Comment: How might one do that? Would you add it to software sources? Or is there an alternative update? --kinda lost at this point, outside the realm of tutorials. --Thanks for all your help thus far, this has really helped!

Comment: The wine package is included in the same PPA repository as is wine1.5.  The only difference is the wine package will always depend on ("require") the latest version of Wine.  So like I said, wait a few days, and give it another shot.  I'm having issues installing Wine on Quantal as well.

Answer (score 1):

All efforts to install wine1.4 or wine 1.5 have been failures - also I thought "answering" would allow me to comment on the original question, unfortunately it did not.  This is not the correct answer, but I'll throw this here:

http://www.noobslab.com/2012/08/install-wine-1511-in-ubuntu.html

Comment: You require a certain amount of reputation to comment on other posts. These restrictions - albeit sometimes obstructive - are in place for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

I did a ppa-purge on the wine ppa, then I followed this solution [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)
I just followed the commands of "sudo apt-get clean" "sudo apt-get autoclean" 
then "sudo apt-get -f install wine1.4". After I did these it installed. Maybe they just updated the packages, idk, but it worked. I just did it also, 7pm eastern time. :D. Take care!