# Problem installing wine on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: wine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is Wine not installable on my system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204393/why-is-wine-not-installable-on-my-system)

I am having problem when installing wine on ubuntu 12.10

I tried to following some tutorial but none of them work.

```
 **root@ubuntu:~# add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa**

 **root@ubuntu:~# apt-get update**

 **root@ubuntu:~# apt-get install wine1.5**

 Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state
 information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This may
 mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are
 using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not
 yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following
 information may help to resolve the situation:

 The following packages have unmet dependencies:  wine1.5 : Depends:
 wine1.5-i386 (= 1.5.16-0ubuntu1) but it is not installable
            Recommends: ttf-droid
            Recommends: ttf-mscorefonts-installer but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: ttf-umefont but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: ttf-unfonts-core but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: winbind but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: winetricks but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
 root@ubuntu:~#
```

Anyone can help me how to solve th problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you have broken packages I would suggest you to use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update -f
```

To fix any broken packages.

and install wine again

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

> And you didn't have to add a repository, since wine is listed by
>   default, a regular `sudo apt-get install wine` would have been enough.

[EDIT]: wow the whole question just changed -.-

Comment: root@ubuntu:~# apt-get install wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.5 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Yes, It is. This is clean install from wubi.

Comment: It seems like the same issue as this : http://askubuntu.com/questions/206564/when-trying-to-install-wine-on-12-10-sudo-command-will-not-let-me-type-in-a-p

Comment: Will update here after following the link you gave.

Comment: Hi Dr_Bunsen, the steps didn't work on my ubuntu :(

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.4 : Depends: wine1.4-i386 (= 1.4.1-0ubuntu1) but it is not installable
bla...bla....bla...           
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: hm, let me google that for you. I can't think of an solution as of yet.

Comment: try: sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
and then sudo apt-get update -f, wait for that and then: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade, and try to install it again

Comment: I am 64 bits too, and wubi should not be a problem, its only a bit slower

Comment: I have been reading alot about Ubuntu failing to install wine. To be honest with you, I have reinstalled 12.10 after upgrading to it from 12.04, since somethings broke(and I didn't care to fix), could this be the problem with you too? I am just guessing here. So no-one blame me XD

Comment: You are going to install 32 bits for testing, because if you have 3.5gb or more ram, you got to install 64 bits.

Comment: Guys - please dont have a conversation in comments - please keep editing your question and answers when you have new points to make.  Please tidy up by deleting your comments above.  Thanks.

Comment: woops, you are right, I am going to delete some things.